# Is there a dynamic way to specify table in Entity Framework Core in .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there a cleaner way to dynamically select a table from a context in Entity Framework? Maybe in a for next loop? If else else then is possible but looks messy and there are about 10 tables that we will need to handle.  All the field names are the same in the tables. We are using .Net 6 already and VS 2022. So if there is a newer feature I am up for it.

```
await using timeFrameContext context = new();

var existsAlready = await context.FiveMin
    .AnyAsync(t => t.ProductName == symbol).ConfigureAwait(false);

var existsAlready = await context.FifteenMin
    .AnyAsync(t => t.ProductName == symbol).ConfigureAwait(false);

var existsAlready = await context.ThirtyMin
    .AnyAsync(t => t.ProductName == symbol).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

etc ...

Comment: `DbContext.Set<TEntity>()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need somthing like this.

```
public async Task<bool> exist<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition) where T : class
{
    return await _contextDb.Set<T>().AnyAsync(condition);
}
```

then you can call in this way

```
var a = await existAsync((FiveMin t) => t.ProductName == symbol);
var b = await existAsync((FifteenMin t) => t.ProductName == symbol);
var c = await existAsync((ThirtyMin t) => t.ProductName == symbol);
```